# DB::raw('MAX gives only values from 1 to 9

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

This function gives only values from 1 to 9 and i don't know why. I've got column proformnumber with numbers from 1 to 10 but this function gives 9. When i deleted some rows it worked correctyly for numbers less than 10.

```
$autoyear = date('Y');
$automonth = date('m');

$autonumber = DB::table("proforms as proforms")
    ->select(\DB::raw('MAX(proformnumber) as proformnumber')) 
    ->where('automonth', '=', $automonth)
    ->where('autoyear', '=', $autoyear)   
    ->get();
```

this is my db
[image]

This is rest of the function code . I am using it to count proform number

```
$autonumber[0]->proformnumber++;
$number = $autonumber[0]->proformnumber;
$number = "$number/$automonth/$autoyear/proforma";
```

Comment: post the records you have on your db please

Comment: Ok. I edited post and pasted screen from db.

Comment: Your proformanumber values are left aligned on the screenshot indicating those strings and not numbers.

Answer (score 1):

This would happen if `proformnumber` was stored as a *string* instead of a *number*.  You can get the numeric maximum by converting.  I think the simplest method in MySQL is to use implicit conversion by adding `0`.

```
MAX(proformnumber + 0)
```

Let this be a lesson in choosing the right data types.